# Convert FRAMESET to IFRAME

Tags: html, iframe, frameset

I'm trying to convert some old code that uses FRAMESET to use IFRAMEs or DIVs. The old code results in two vertical frames, the left one being 30% of the window initially. The user can move the dividing line to change the proportions. The old code (stripped down) is:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
    <FRAMESET frameSpacing="3" frameBorder="0" cols=30%,* >
    <FRAME id="contentGenerator" src="content.html"  scrolling="no">
    <FRAME id="content" src="startNSM.html" >
    </FRAMESET>
</HTML>
```

What I've got so far is:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>

<STYLE>
#cgDiv {
    HEIGHT: 100%; WIDTH: 30%; VERTICAL-ALIGN: top; POSITION: fixed
}
#contentGenerator {
    HEIGHT: 100%    
}
#cDiv {
    HEIGHT: 100%; WIDTH: 70%; VERTICAL-ALIGN: top; POSITION: relative
}
#content {
    HEIGHT: 100%
}
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY >
<DIV id="cgDiv">
    <IFRAME id="contentGenerator" src="content.html">
    </IFRAME>
</DIV>
<DIV id="cDiv">
    <IFRAME id="content" src="startNSM.html">
    </IFRAME>
</DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

What this does is display the first IFRAME in 30% of the window, but not the second frame.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Try Changing CSS to the following

```
#cgDiv {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 30%;
}

#contentGenerator, #content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#cDiv {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 69.5%;
}

body { margin: 0}
```

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't work.  I shouldn't have said the second frame doesn't appear. A bit of the frame boundary appears at the bottom of the window, to the right of the first frame. The only difference now is that the second frame looks to be the correct width. It's still not aligned with the top of the window.

Comment: oh sorry my fault, i forgot to remove the 'margin-left: 30%;' from the #cDiv.
Also, i there is a space between the window border and the frame border adding body {margin: 0} CSS rule should help.

i edited my answer above

Comment: an advice in general:

To solve problems like this, Firefox browser with the firebug extension is imho the best tool to work with. it lets you try your CSS rules in a wysiwyg way in the browser